# Url-prefix and Flask-Babel

Tags: python, flask

I use Flask-Babel for translating.
Use function to determine locale:

```
LANGUAGES = ['en', 'ru']

@babel.localeselector
def get_locale():
    return request.accept_languages.best_match(LANGUAGES)
```

How can I add url-prefix for everyone url according to locale, for example?

```
ru/quotes
```

or

```
en/quotes
```

And I would like to set link for selecting language in template. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python flask web application with multilanguages support by host and prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686087/python-flask-web-application-with-multilanguages-support-by-host-and-prefix)