# Format canonical URL structure correctly with URL Processors

Tags: python, internationalization, flask, culture

**EDIT:** Could you read my question more carefully? This question is specific and not [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923647/format-canonical-url-structure?noredirect=1#comment36847764_23923647) as has been said. Obviously I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686087/python-flask-web-application-with-multilanguages-support-by-host-and-prefix) before post.

---

In this demo code from the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/urlprocessors/#internationalized-application-urls), the fragment after the lang parameter will be static. So, in English `/en/about`, and for example, in Portuguese `/pt/about`. Well, the correct, should be `/pt/sobre`.

Any idea about the correct way to make that with URL Processors?

```
from flask import Flask, g

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.url_defaults
def add_language_code(endpoint, values):
    if 'lang_code' in values or not g.lang_code:
        return
    if app.url_map.is_endpoint_expecting(endpoint, 'lang_code'):
        values['lang_code'] = g.lang_code

@app.url_value_preprocessor
def pull_lang_code(endpoint, values):
    g.lang_code = values.pop('lang_code', None)

@app.route('/<lang_code>/')
def index():
    ...

@app.route('/<lang_code>/about')
def about():
```

Comment: @Martijn Pieters This question is not duplicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, you already have language prefix. So you need have several translations for next part.

The easiest way it use several routes or converters:

```
@app.route('/<lang_code>/about')
@app.route('/<lang_code>/sobre')
def about():
    pass
```

or

```
@app.route('/<lang_code>/<any(about,sobre):about>')
def about(about):
    pass
```

But it hard to support and add new languages.

Second way is change route method to translate special words or add special translate processor converter, last more interesting and implicit:

```
from werkzeug.routing import AnyConverter


languages = ['en', 'pt']


def translate_url(word, language):
    if language == 'pt' and word == 'about':
        return 'sobre'
    return word


class TranslateConverter(AnyConverter):

    def __init__(self, map, item):
        AnyConverter.__init__(self, map, *[translate_url(item, language) 
                                           for language in languages])


app.url_map.converters['tr'] = TranslateConverter


@app.route('/<lang_code>/<tr(about):about>')
def about(about):
    pass
```

But this example have next issue:

```
/en/about
/en/sorbe
/pt/about
/pt/sorbe
```

is valid urls, but you can also try use own `Rule` class (`Flask.url_rule_class`) where in `match` method you can process this cases:

```
from werkzeug.routing import AnyConverter, Rule


class TranslateConverter(AnyConverter):

    def __init__(self, map, item):
        self.language_pairs = {language: translate_url(item, language)
                               for language in languages}
        AnyConverter.__init__(self, map, *tuple(self.language_pairs.values()))


class TranslateCorrelationRule(Rule):

    def match(self, path):
        result = Rule.match(self, path)
        if result is None:
            return result
        lang_code = result.get('lang_code')
        if lang_code is None:
            return result
        for name, value in self._converters.items():
            if not isinstance(value, TranslateConverter):
                continue
            if value.language_pairs[lang_code] != result[name]:
                return
        return result


app.url_map.converters['tr'] = TranslateConverter
app.url_rule_class = TranslateCorrelationRule
```

If you will simplify `url_for` usage for this examples you can use next sample:

```
@app.url_value_preprocessor
def pull_lang_code(endpoint, values):
    if not values:
        return
    g.lang_code = values.pop('lang_code', None)
    for key, value in values.items():
        if key.startswith('_'):
            values.pop(key)


class TranslateCorrelationRule(Rule):

    def _update_translate_values(self, values):
        lang_code = values.get('lang_code', getattr(g, 'lang_code', None))
        if lang_code is None:
            return values
        values = values.copy()
        for argument in self.arguments:
            if argument in values:
                continue
            converter = self._converters[argument]
            if not isinstance(converter, TranslateConverter):
                continue
            values[argument] = converter.language_pairs[lang_code]
        return values

    def suitable_for(self, values, method=None):
        return Rule.suitable_for(self, self._update_translate_values(values),
                                 method)

    def build(self, values, append_unknown=True):
        return Rule.build(self, self._update_translate_values(values),
                          append_unknown)
```

Comment: I stop to understand when you say : If you will simplify url_for... What do you mean? thanks. After see the edits, i think in the edit 7, the deleted lines should be recovered to effects of clarification.

Comment: When you use `@app.route('/<lang_code>/<tr(about):about>')` you need process `lang_code` and `about` arguments. To skip it in route you can use `@app.url_value_preprocessor` and pop special values. But to create url with `url_for` you also need send it to arguments or set it in `@app.url_defaults` as in you example with `lang_code`. Now it will look like `url_for('about', _about='about')` for english and `url_for('about', _about='sobre')` for portuguese, but explicitly set `_about` argument not necessary. With last sample you can use just `url_for('about')` or `url_for('about', lang_code=lng)`