# Flask - how can I always include language code in url

Tags: python, internationalization, flask

I am starting with Flask for a couple weeks and is trying to implement i18n and l10n to my Flask app.
This is the behavior that I really want to implement:

> User enters `website.com` will be redirected to `website.com/en/` or `website.com/fr/` depends on their Accept-Languages header or default language in their settings.

This is my current implementation:

```
# main_blueprint.py
mainBlueprint = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@mainBlueprint.route('/')
def index(lang):
    return "lang: %" % lang


# application.py
app.register_blueprint(mainBlueprint, url_defaults={'lang': 'en'})
app.register_blueprint(mainBlueprint, url_prefix='/<lang>')
```

This way, when I type `website.com` or `website.com/en/` it will respond with just `website.com`. Unless I type `website.com/fr` it would respond with `/fr/`. However, I want to always include `/en/` even if it is the default option.

---

I have tried the guide [URL Processors pattern](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/urlprocessors/) in Flask doc, but when I typed `website.com` it responded with `404 error`. It only worked fine when I include the `language_code` into the url—which is not the behavior that I want.

---

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python flask web application with multilanguages support by host and prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686087/python-flask-web-application-with-multilanguages-support-by-host-and-prefix)

Comment: @tbicr: I have read your question and the answers too, and have tried all of them. The problem is that I want to always include `/en/` or `/fr/` in the urls. Currently I can only include other language codes but not `en` :(

Comment: Look like you need only `app.register_blueprint(mainBlueprint, url_defaults='/<lang>')`. You always can redirect to en with default blueprint if you need, for example, in `before_request` for your default blueprint.

Comment: How can I vote you up @tbicr? :D Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look like you need only one blueprint:

```
app.register_blueprint(mainBlueprint, url_defaults='/<lang>')
```

But you should decide behaviour for default blueprint route:

1. It can return 404:

   ```
   app.register_blueprint(mainBlueprint, url_defaults='/<lang>')
   ```
2. It can redirect to `/en` blueprint:

   ```
   @mainBlueprint.before_request
   def x(*args, **kwargs):
       if not request.view_args.get('lang'):
           return redirect('/en' + request.full_path)

   app.register_blueprint(mainBlueprint, url_defaults={'lang': None})
   app.register_blueprint(mainBlueprint, url_prefix='/<lang>')
   ```

Comment: this before request always redirects to en ? I need to redirect to the current page as user is visiting. For example when visitor is at /en/about and changes language he must be at /ka/about is that possible  ?